# Connecting App for Office with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, office365-apps

We created an App for Office from the standard template in VS 2013. We need the app to connect to an MVC project instead of the default web project. So, we replaced the one with an MVC 5 Web API 2 project. If we run the MVC project by itself, it runs well in a browser.

The problem is when we start the App for Office and we expect to see it in a task panel in Word or Excel. VS gives us a popup: “There were deployment errors. Continue?” If we hit “Yes” things work fine but something must be wrong. Nothing specific in the Output window and the only log we get is 1 failed deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Make sure you select the MVC project in the “Web Project” property of the App for Office. You can access that by selecting your App project in Solution Explorer and hitting F4 to open its Properties window.

Also, make sure you select a valid web page for Source location in the manifest, which I assume you do, because you say “it works” if you click Continue on the error popup.